# How do I display only datepart of datetime field in LINQ query?

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, datetime

I have a datetime field in a database which when retrieved should only display the date without the time. Can you please let me know how to do it? Here is the query I wrote:

```
    var queryProductEventCustomers = (from r in DbContext.ProductEventCustomers
                                      from s in DbContext.CustomerProducts
                                      where r.Customers_Id == customerID && r.Customers_Id 
                                      == s.Customers_Id && s.Products_Id == productID
                                      select new
                                            {
                                               r.Id,
                                               r.Customers_Id,
                                               r.StartTime
```

The starttime is a datetime field. So, can you please let me know how to do it?

Comment: @nishanth, were you able to get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

Just choose the date portion:

```
select new
{
     Id = r.Id,
     Cust_id = r.Customers_Id,
     Date = r.StartTime.Date
}
```

Comment: No date property is coming up after r.starttime

Comment: That won't compile. You need to specify a member for the date.

Comment: Nishanth - what is the data type of StartTime?

Comment: DateTime should have a "Date" property, so StartTime.Date should work.  You should probably verify in your code that StartTime is actually a DateTime and not some other type of field (e.g. string, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select new
{
     ID = r.Id,
     CustomerID = r.Customers_Id,
     StartDate = r.StartTime.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
}
```

Comment: That won't compile. You need to specify a member for the date.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Short Date format:

```
r.StartTime.ToString("d", DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo)
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx

The link shows you how to work with all standard date and time formats.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`ToShortDateString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.toshortdatestring.aspx) method on DateTime.

```
select new
{
     Id = r.Id,
     Customers_Id = r.Customers_Id,
     Date = r.StartTime.ToShortDateString()
}
```